# .hgignore not working for me

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to setup .hgignore for a project.  The .hgignore file is in the project root next to the .hg file.  The output from a status is below, I'd like to ignore all files in the sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug and sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp directories.  I've tried various combinations of forward/back slashes and wildcards but can't get it to work.  Any suggestions?

```
C:\sdcard>hg st
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\Clock_1.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\Clock_2.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\Cm3Start.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\Control_Reg_1.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\CyDmac.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\CyFlash.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\CyLib.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\CySpc.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\SPIM_1.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\SPIM_1_INT.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\SPIM_1_PM.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\TX.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\UART_1.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\UART_1_INT.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\UART_1_PM.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\clk.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\core_cm3.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\cyPm.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\cyfitter_cfg.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\cyutils.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\ff.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\main.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\miso.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\mmc.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\mosi.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\sdcard.a
M sdcard.cydsn\ARM_GCC_441\Debug\ss.lst
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\lcpsoc3\index
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\sdcard.ctl
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\sdcard.cyfit
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\sdcard.rpt
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\sdcard.v
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\sdcard.vh2
M sdcard.cydsn\codegentemp\sdcard_timing.xml
M sdcard.cydsn\sdcard.cyfit
M sdcard.cydsn\sdcard.cyprj
M sdcard.cydsn\sdcard.cyprj.sean
M sdcard.cydsn\sdcard.rpt
M sdcard.cywrk
M sdcard.cywrk.sean
? .hgignore
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are already tracking the files, which you are, after you do a

`hg add .hgignore`

you will need to `forget` the files that you don't want to track anymore. `.hgignore` doesn't get ignore files you are already tracking.

Comment: Yup, this one catches a lot of people and @msarchet has the right answer.  Ignoring only affects untracked file, files already added are outside the purview of `.hgignore`.  One great side effect of this is you can do something like put `*.jar` in your ignore and then still `hg add aspecific.jar` as an exception.

Comment: @ry4an I think I answer one to 2 questions a week that are because of something related to this exact issues, but always enough different to not be dupes.

Comment: agree completely.  And it's a feature I really like, but it's clearly not intuitive enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ignore file to your repository. ie:

```
hg add .hgignore
```

The ignore file is versioned like any other file, it's just that the hg tools attach special meaning to its contents.