# Mercurial hgignore file won't ignore a certain file

Tags: mercurial

I have a file named A/B/SomeFile.dll that gets generated by visual studio on each compile.

In my .hgignore file I have included:

```
SomeFile.dll
A/B/SomeFile.dll
*SomeFile.dll
```

and yet, every recompile makes mercurial think the file has been modified. (this is not a local hgignore file, but what it is the latest committed file)

I have triple verified it is spelled correctly and the cases are the exact same. Now I am lost.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248532/hgignore-not-working-for-me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you didn't add the file to the repo before you added it to .ignore file. If you did, you will need to "hg remove" it from the repository, then commit.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop tracking the file in mercurial; `.hgignore` is ignored for files already tracked in the repository.