# How to ignore .bak files in Mercurial .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

How can I adjust my current `.hgingore`

```
syntax: glob
oes
images
*.bak
```

So that it ignores all `.bak` files?  This isn't working, when I open the commit dialog it still shows a bunch of `.php.bak` files.

`*.bak` of course isn't working

Comment: What do you mean by 'the commit dialog'? Are you using TortoiseHg?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.hgignore not working for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248532/hgignore-not-working-for-me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This keeps new .bak files from being added to the Repo. If they are already in the repo, then they will still be tracked. You can `hg forget` the files to remove them from future revisions in the repo and then with *.bak in .hgignore, you won't be asked to add them back in.